# I'm new to Xamarin and mobile app development. Created a xamarin account. How do I link a computer to my xamarin account

Tags: xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin and mobile app development. Created a xamarin account. There is a section that lists computers which are linked to the Xamarin account. I don't see an option to link a computer to the account. How is this done?

Comment: you do it when you launch Visual Studio, although I don't think the Xamarin licensing portal is relevant any more - now you would probably put in your Microsoft/MSDN account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I ask why you need to link a computer to the account? I don't have any computers linked either but I'm able to develop in VS just fine. Your Microsoft account is what is connected in VS.

Answer (score 1):

Previously before Xamarin acquired by Microsoft and having a paid license, you can only linked your account up to maximum of 4 computers. After Microsoft acquired Xamarin and remove the license, this restriction is no longer applicable. The license is now retrieve from your Microsoft account.